# How to Compile GCC 9.1 Targeting 64-bit Windows in WSL

Tags: windows, gcc, cross-compiling

Since GCC 9.1 was recently released, I wanted to try it out a bit. It works fine natively on WSL (Debian), but I also wanted to try building it to target Windows x64. Unfortunately, I have not had any success in doing this; I have tried two different --target arguments (x86_64-pc-windows and x86_64-pc-msys), but partway through running make, I always get an error saying the configuration is not supported. Am I just using the wrong target architecture, or am I missing something more fundamental? I've never built GCC for cross-compiling before.